# Taming exports of function call in R

Tags: r, scope

I'm making a call to
[goseq::goseq](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/goseq.html).
After that, the namespace (if that's the right word) is all upset.

I suppose this goes back to liberal use of `library(...)` in the package or its dependencies.

How can I prevent the call from masking any objects in my namespace?

```
...
Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:parallel’:

    clusterApply, clusterApplyLB, clusterCall, clusterEvalQ, clusterExport,
    clusterMap, parApply, parCapply, parLapply, parLapplyLB, parRapply, parSapply,
    parSapplyLB

The following objects are masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    combine, intersect, setdiff, union

[... ETC, ETC ...]

Attaching package: ‘AnnotationDbi’

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    select
```

P.S.

I would consider as an answer if somebody could just formulate the problem in the appropriate technical terms. Why, for example, `rlang::env_names(rlang::current_env())` only shows the variables I have set, not the objects floating around, and where can I find those instead? I couldn't find good pointers due to false positives.

Comment: This is a bug in the package which should be reported to the maintainers: `library` mustn’t be used in packages, and nowadays the package couldn’t be submitted in its current form to Bioconductor, as far as I know. Unfortunately there’s very little you can do to work around this bug, short of patching the `library` function itself before invoking the goseq package function.

Comment: Regarding your edit, attached names live in separate, attached environments. You can see them by running `search()`. And you can list them by using, e.g. `ls(2)` (to list the names in the second environment returned by `search()`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: interesting. So, perhaps I could detect which packages have been attached and detach them? Also, is the order of appearance in `search()` significant?

Comment: True, you can detach them. And yes, the order is important: environments at lower positions override environments with higher positions. That’s why functions from packages can override those from base: because base is always at the highest position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a proof of concept, this seems to work.
Thanks to @KonradRudolph for the comments.

```
# install.packages("crunch")

# Wrap functions that do `library(...)`
# and force-detach all attached packages
unattach_packages <- function(f) {
  requireNamespace("crunch")

  # wrapper for f
  function(...) {
    base::with(
      crunch::ContextManager(
        enter = base::search,
        exit = function() {
          for (pkg in setdiff(base::search(), enter)) {
            base::detach(pkg, character.only = TRUE, force = TRUE)
          }
        },
        # this overwrites the variable `enter`, if existent
        as = "enter"
      ),
      {
        f(...)
      }
    )
  }
}

# Usage:
unattach_packages(function(x, y) { library(goseq); x + y })(1, 2)
```